# RecurrenceTable with vectors

Tags: difference-equations

Is there a way to call parts of a vector in `RecurrenceTable`? This does not work:

```
RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == {n[t][[1]]}, n[1] == {0}}, n, {t, 1, 3}]

(* Out[1]= RecurrenceTable[{n[1 + t] == {t}, n[1] == {0}}, n, {t, 1, 3}] *)
```

I would like to keep the vector structure because the original problem should be expanded to more dimensions.

ps: The original problem is

```
a[x_] := {{0, 2/(1 + x)}, {.8, .2}};
RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == a[n[t][[2]]].n[t],n[1] == {0, 1}}, n, {t, 1, 25}]

During evaluation of In[1]:= Part::partw: Part 2 of n[t] does not exist.
```

what does not run because apparently also in this example the "Part" command is executed before the `RecurrenceTable`.

Comment: Have you tried [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) instead of `Part`?

Comment: @Michael E2 is correct: `RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == a[Indexed[n[t], 2]].n[t],  n[1] == {0, 1}}, n, {t, 1, 10}]' seems to work fine.

Comment: @Michael E2, thank you, that's perfect. I like the solution with Indexed because the code stays clear.

Answer (score 1):

RecurrenceTable works fine with vectors. Here's an example:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}};
RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == a.n[t], n[1] == {1, 1}}, n, {t, 1, 3}]
```

It returns the first three vectors.

For your specific problem, I would program it directly using recursions (rather than using RecurrenceTable, since you have greater control). Here is one possible implementation where I have replaced your vector n with the pair {n,m}.

```
a[x_] := {{0, 2/(1 + x)}, {.8, .2}}; 
n[t_] := (a[(m[t - 1])].{n[t - 1], m[t - 1]})[[1]];
m[t_] := (a[(m[t - 1])].{n[t - 1], m[t - 1]})[[2]];
{n[1], m[1]} = {1, 2};
```

Now you can evaluate any given values:

```
{n[2], m[2]}
{1.33333, 1.2}
```

or evaluate a range:

```
{n[#], m[#]} & /@ Range[10]
```

Comment: Yes that works, but how can you call single parts of the vector in the RecurrenceTable? See the example in the ps. part of the question.